# Yichud with close relatives in the past

Tags: yichud-seclusion, kerovim-close-relatives

The *gemarra* in [Kiddushin 81b](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.81b.8?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi) says that it is permitted to seclude oneself (yichud) with a close relative such as a mother or sister, despite the fact that seclusion with people who it is forbidden to marry is forbidden.

> מִתְיַיחֵד אָדָם עִם אִמּוֹ אָמַר רַב יְהוּדָה אָמַר רַב אַסִּי מִתְיַיחֵד אָדָם עִם אֲחוֹתוֹ וְדָר עִם אִמּוֹ וְעִם בִּתּוֹ כִּי אַמְרִ[יתַ]הּ קַמֵּיהּ דִּשְׁמוּאֵל אָמַר אָסוּר לְהִתְיַיחֵד עִם כׇּל עֲרָיוֹת שֶׁבַּתּוֹרָה וַאֲפִילּוּ עִם בְּהֵמָה

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.81b.8?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Kiddushin.81b.8.1&vhe2=Vilna_Edition&lang2=bi) there gives an explanation for this exception:

> ודר עם אמו או עם בתו - דלא תקיף יצריה עלייהו דאהנו ביה אנשי כנסת הגדולה דלא מגרי בקרובתא מכי כחלינהו ונקרינהו לעיניה כו' (סנהדרין דף סד.):
>
> A person can live with their mother or their daughter - Since the sexual inclination isn't so strong towards them, since the Anshei Kenesses HaGedolah were succesful to remove the desire towards relatives, when they blinded the evil inclination, as in Sanhedrin 64a.

As Rashi cites, the Anshei Kenesses HaGedolah were succesful at decreasing the sexual drive towards relatives. This is why people are naturally not attracted to their mother, sister, and daughter. This permits seclusion with them.

However, that implies that before they did this, people *were* attracted to these relatives. It also implies that seclusion would be forbidden. Is this correct? How did normal family life work if a person couldn't be alone with their mother, sister, or daughter?

Comment: Towards the end of the second temple period or the first?

Comment: @Harel13 clearly the second

Comment: @רבותמחשבות The Anshei Knesset Hagedolah existed at the end of the 2nd temple period?

Comment: Yes. I was going to add something along those lines to my previous comment but didn't have time. In any case, consider that Shimon Hatzaddik was one of the remnants of the Knesset and whatever exact era you may identify him with, he was still early on.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Harel13 yes; read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Assembly

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Can you quote the relevant part? I'm not seeing any statement on their having existed at the end of the 2nd temple. I have studied the subject in the past and I know there are academic views that hold that whenever the term 'knesset' is used in the mishna it alludes to a group that evolved out of the AK"H, but I don't get the sense that most members on MY accept that view (I myself feel it's too much of a stretch).

Comment: Not really the "end", but during the Second Temple period. The Gemara in Sanhedrin darshens this story from Nechemia, and the people in the Anshei Knesses Hagedolah lived at the start and middle of the Second Temple.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel can you clarify what you don't understand

Comment: Robev, It seems the crux of your posting is " How did normal family life work if a person couldn't be alone with their mother, sister, or daughter?". Is that right? If so this may need more elaboration. Generally, there are probably many areas of life starting at year X which cannot be compared with "normalcy" after Y historical period; laws of ritual purity certainly come to mind. I would prefer if you would be asking "is there any proof to this assertion"; that is hinted in "is this correct", I guess. Cheerio